why we could not open chrome side panel when clicking a context menu item?
in my chrome extension, i'd like to open the side panel when user clicking a context menu item. but below error thrown:
sidePanel.open() may only be called in response to a user gesture.
in the extension, a context menu item added, in the click handler chrome.sidePanel.open() called to open the side panel.
context menu clicking could not be regarded as user gesture?
// add an context menu item

chrome.contextMenus.create({

  id: 'my-ctx-menu-item-id',

 title:'test item',

  contexts:['selection'],

})

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async(info, tab) => {
  if(info.menuItemId === 'my-ctx-menu-item-id') {
    // to open sidePanel
    chrome.sidePanel.open({ tabId: tab.id}) // ==> this will raise error: sidePanel.open() may only be called in response to a user gesture.    
  }
})


After calling chrome.tabs.query(), the chrome.contextMenus.onClicked handler doesn't count as user-activated anymore. You can remove the call to chrome.tabs.query(), and replace chrome.sidePanel.open({ tabId: tabs[0].id}) with chrome.sidePanel.open({ tabId: tab.id });

@ThomasMueller you're right. tab.id can be used in chrome.sidePanel.open(), but the error is the same
